# Add gesture to custom component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, hammer.js

I have a custom menu i've built because i need a menu with specific functions and behaviours and modifying the Ionic's menu component seemed to be too much work for what i need, so here's my problem:

The menu should have a **swipe to right** gesture where if you swipe/drag from the left to right the menu is showed. Even with the "sandwich" icon on top, some users have tried to drag/swipe to get the menu, so that's why it needs to have a gesture too.

This is my `app.html`

```
<wabiz-menu [ngClass]="{'menuNotShown': !isMenuShown, 'menuShown': isMenuShown }" *ngIf="logedIn" (swipe)="swipeMenu($event)"></wabiz-menu>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false" [ngClass]="{'menu-not-shown': logedIn }"></ion-nav>
```

As you can see i have a `(swipe)` gesture in my menu, but it doesn't work. I've also tried to implement it in my `<ion-nav>`, but my `swipeMenu` function never executes.

So far i haven't tried anything from my menu `.ts` file.

Do i need to use another event instead of `(swipe)`? Should i create an event on my custom menu `.ts` file? Should i declare some sort of `@input()` of an event type so it can be called?

Any idea is welcome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using `Ionic component` (i.e. you are using `custom menu` component) you must implement `Gesture` (i.e. `swipe`)  functionality using [**Hammerjs**](http://hammerjs.github.io/examples/). Otherwise, it won't work.

Here you can find out the [**Hammer.Swipe(options)**](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/).

Comment: Nice, i'll try it soon and let you know.

Comment: Worked like a charm, had to search for some tutorials about using it with Angular, but turns out Angular already has some support for its configuration in `@angular/platform-browser`. Thanks man.